# sympy Numpy clash

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

in these SIMPLE code 
i was getting ATTRIBUTE ERROR , may be because of np,sym, clashing
help me to resolve it.

```
import sympy as sym
x=sym.Symbol('x')
def f(x):
    return (x**2*np.exp(x))/((np.exp(x)-1)**2)
sym.integrate(f(x),x)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-574a1c7346b8> in <module>
      3 def f(x):
      4     return (x**2*np.exp(x))/((np.exp(x)-1)**2)
----> 5 sym.integrate(f(x),x)

<ipython-input-48-574a1c7346b8> in f(x)
      2 x=sym.Symbol('x')
      3 def f(x):
----> 4     return (x**2*np.exp(x))/((np.exp(x)-1)**2)
      5 sym.integrate(f(x),x)

AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

Comment: please, format properly your code and also the traceback, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186

Comment: `np.exp`, when given a non-numeric object like a `sympy` `Symbol` tries to pass the task to a method of the same name.  Hence the error.  There's a `sym.exp`, but `x.exp()` does not work.  As a general use `sympy` code on `Symbols`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I suppose you cannot use np functions. This works:

```
x = sym.Symbol('x')

def f(x):
    return (x**2*sym.exp(x))/((sym.exp(x)-1)**2)

print(sym.integrate(f(x),x))
```

Comment: Thanks man , it helped , anyway can you please share me how code this same integral with limits 0 to inf , when i tried that it showed again an error ,"over flow encountered due in double scalers"

Comment: I did `sym.integrate(f(x),(x,0,sym.oo))` There's a lot of docs here https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html

Comment: `from scipy.integrate import quad    

import numpy as np


def f(x):
    return (x**2*np.exp(x))/((np.exp(x)-1)**2)
print(quad(f,0,np.inf))`





ans is :
_(nan, nan)
C:\Users\Subham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:7: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  import sys
C:\Users\Subham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  import sys_

Comment: @Subham, why are you using a `scipy.integrate` function on a `sympy` function?  You just found that `np.exp` doesn't work with `sympy`.  `scipy` is an extension of `numpy`.